# How to avoid storing duplicate dataframe values in memory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe:

```
   Game ID  Play Number   Play Type  Yard Gain  Home Win  Final Home Score  Final Away Score
0        1            1        Pass         10      True                28                14
1        1            2         Run          5      True                28                14
2        1            3        Pass         12      True                28                14
3        1            4        Pass          8      True                28                14
4        1            5  Field Goal          0      True                28                14
```

Last 3 columns have same information. How to avoid storing duplicate values in memory and display by forward filling instead? Or is only option to split table, one with play-by-play data and another where each row is a game?

Answer (score 2):

If you were doing this in a database, you would probably have two tables, `games` containing `Game ID`, `Home Win`, `Final Home Score` and `Final Away Score` and `plays` containing `Game ID`, `Play Number`, `Play Type` and `Yard Gain`, and then `JOIN` them in a query using `Game ID`. You can do the same using `pandas` (assuming `df` is your existing data):

```
plays = df.drop(['Home Win','Final Home Score', 'Final Away Score'], axis=1)
#
#    Game ID  Play Number   Play Type  Yard Gain
# 0        1            1        Pass         10
# 1        1            2         Run          5
# 2        1            3        Pass         12
# 3        1            4        Pass          8
# 4        1            5  Field Goal          0

games = df[['Game ID', 'Home Win', 'Final Home Score', 'Final Away Score']].drop_duplicates(keep='first')
#
#    Game ID  Home Win  Final Home Score  Final Away Score
# 0        1      True                28                14

out = games.merge(plays, on='Game ID')
```

Output

```
   Game ID  Home Win  Final Home Score  Final Away Score  Play Number   Play Type  Yard Gain
0        1      True                28                14            1        Pass         10
1        1      True                28                14            2         Run          5
2        1      True                28                14            3        Pass         12
3        1      True                28                14            4        Pass          8
4        1      True                28                14            5  Field Goal          0
```

You can do the merge in the opposite direction to achieve your starting point.